# File types in Nautilus - how to distinguish between different file types?

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, file-format, extension

Under file `Type` column in `Nautilus`, I get file categories like *Image*, *Document*, etc. I need to sort files according to file format. Is there a way make a distinction, based on file formats?

Comment: If you have the same question as someone else 1½ years ago, please try to contribute to that question e. g. by adding a bounty. Voted to close as a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I stop Files from oversimplifying file types?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/291839/how-can-i-stop-files-from-oversimplifying-file-types)

Answer (score 2):

#### How to select / distinguish filetypes in nautilus

1. In a nautilus window, choose icon view:

   [image]
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (or choose *Edit* > *Select Items Matching...*), and type your searched properties:

   [image]
3. The items that fulfill the requirements are selected:

   [image]

Comment: @tagMacher was this the kind of answer you were looking for?

Comment: Actually what you suggested is the way I should have done; I could also have worked more efficiently than what I did, by opening up a Terminal window. The real issue is a successive dumbing down of Ubuntu that concerns me; I wanted to ask others if there is going to be a reversal in future versions, or is Ubuntu going the way of Microsoft Windows; David Foerster and others feel this is irrelevent and out of place so I will shut up here.