# File Manager Type Classification - Document (pdf/docx)

Tags: nautilus, pdf, mime-type, document, doc

I have a folder with pdf, doc and docx files, I would like to sort them using the default File manager, displaying pdfs and word docs separately. Unfortunately in the 'Type' column, they are all considered 'Document'. Is there any way I can change this to sort them separately?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File types in Nautilus - how to distinguish between jpg and tiff?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/589904/file-types-in-nautilus-how-to-distinguish-between-jpg-and-tiff)

Comment: The actual dupe should be http://askubuntu.com/questions/291839/how-can-i-stop-files-from-oversimplifying-file-types

Answer (score 1):

you could try to add the "MIME Type" to the attributes. Just right click on one of the attributes ( Name, Type, Size, ...) and select "MIME Type".

Thomas