# How to order file by extension nautilus

Tags: nautilus, files

I have a bunch of auxiliary files produced by LaTeX compilations, that I want to get rid of and just keep the `.tex` files.

I already read [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/291839/29595) that answer **partially** what I want, because I can order the files by MIME type and then select and cancel.

But it does not answers totally because, for example, `.aux`, `.gls`, `brf` and `.tex` files are all with MIME type `'text/x-tex'`, as you can see in the picture

[image]

So, how can I do it?

PS: I do not have `sudo` privileges on this computer, since it is my workstation and not my personal PC, so it is excluded installing other file managers or modify global configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

[image: order]Something like this?

When hitting search and then the + button on the right you have the ability to choose some files... Sorry, but I'm not sure if it's that you're searching for...

Comment: Good idea but it does not solve, because it uses the MIME type of the files, and it shows the exact behaviour that come out in the MIME type column, so files with different extensions are there together. EDIT: Actually it is even worse, because it shows ALL TeX-related documents, so also `.bibtex` and such :)

Answer (score 0):

You could hit the search-button, type in .tex, wait for the result, mark them all, right-click and copy or move them to a new folder.

Comment: If you know how to do the opposite, that would be an answer I would accept!

Answer (score 0):

It seems no "Files" file manager out there knows about extensions anymore. All of Nautilus, Nemo, and Thunar only sort by Type or Mime-type.

In the end I went back to a 2-panel commander. There's Krusader, but has a huge-ish footprint (129MiB including all dependencies that I didn't have), and starts up slow, but at least it knows about extensions.

If you like features and want something lighter and even more powerful, use Total Commander (the trial version only annoys you once on each start, and is fully functional). The downside of running it in wine is the lack of opening/executing files in native Linux apps, and drag/drop.